# Golang - Supersede Embedded Structure for URL Encoding Parameters

Tags: api, go, url-encoding

I have multiple structures with the same format as `MapParameters` that are passed to the `encodeParams` function. Unfortunately, using that function against these structures produces unwanted encoding including the embedded structure name. Is there anyway I can fix this using `reflect` without using a huge switch library of type assertions?

```
// Desired Encoding
&required_param=1

// Current Encoding
%5BRequired%5D&required_param=1 

// Desired
type MapParameters struct {
  Required struct { ... }
  Optional struct { ... }
}

// Current
type MapParameters struct {
  MapRequired
  MapOptional
}

type MapRequired struct { ... }
type MapOptional struct { ... }

func encodeParams(s string, opt interface{}) (string, error) {
  v := reflect.ValueOf(opt)
  if v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && v.IsNil() {
    return s, nil
  }

  u, err := url.Parse(s)
  if err != nil {
    return s, err
  }

  // from github.com/google/go-querystring/query
  qs, err := query.Values(opt)
  if err != nil {
    return s, err
  }

  u.RawQuery = u.RawQuery + qs.Encode()
  return u.String(), nil
}
```

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/6C8yUPu34E generate url string `B=b&C=2&D=d&a=1` in my test project, so it seems your code should work.

Comment: Yes that is using my current code. I would prefer to have the structure embedded without the extra declared struct.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous not mean embed, they are completely different two thing. Embedding means the fields of nested struct will present to outer struct. Anonymous just missing the struct name. you are expecting anonymous structs to be embedded, it is not a good idea.

Anyhow, if you want encoding anonymous as embedded, change the code in `url-encoding` lib https://github.com/google/go-querystring/blob/master/query/encode.go

```
if /*sf.Anonymous &&*/ sv.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
    // save embedded struct for later processing
    embedded = append(embedded, sv)
    continue
}
```

please note `sf.Anonymous` not mean anonymous in real, it means embedded as the comment saying

```
type StructField struct {
    ...
    Index     []int     // index sequence for Type.FieldByIndex
    Anonymous bool      // is an embedded field
}
```